# Windows 8 Blank App + DEP0700 error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I've found a few posts mentioning this error, but none that have helped.  I created a new C# Windows Store project, and when I try to build and run it on the simulator, I get the following error in visual studio:

```
Error   1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80072EE4: The Visual Elements extension failed while processing the Notification element. (0x80073cf6)    TestDeploy
```

Here are the details from running a Power Shell command mentioned in a different post:

```
12/18/2012 3:03:59 PM   404 Error   error 0x80073CF6: AppX Deployment operation failed. The specific error text for this failure is: error 0x80072EE4: The Visual Elements extension failed while processing the Notification element.  
12/18/2012 3:03:59 PM   401 Error   Deployment Register operation on Package cc8bb3bb-d444-4dbe-ae12-64684b12b727_1.0.0.0_neutral__2awvr17ztw74c from:  (C:\Users\myself\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestDeploy\TestDeploy\bin\Debug\AppX\AppxManifest.xml)  failed with error 0x80073CF6. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.   
12/18/2012 3:03:59 PM   605 Information The last successful state reached was PackagesInUseClosed.  
12/18/2012 3:03:59 PM   300 Error   error 0x80073CF6: Cannot register the cc8bb3bb-d444-4dbe-ae12-64684b12b727_1.0.0.0_neutral__2awvr17ztw74c package due to the following error: Package could not be registered.
.   
12/18/2012 3:03:59 PM   316 Error   error 0x80072EE4: Cannot register the cc8bb3bb-d444-4dbe-ae12-64684b12b727_1.0.0.0_neutral__2awvr17ztw74c package because the following error was encountered during the registration of the windows.visualElements extension: <Error message string not found>.    
12/18/2012 3:03:59 PM   306 Error   error 0x80072EE4: While installing the cc8bb3bb-d444-4dbe-ae12-64684b12b727_1.0.0.0_neutral__2awvr17ztw74c package, the system failed to register the windows.visualElements extension due to the following error: <Error message string not found>.    
12/18/2012 3:03:59 PM   5092    Error   error 0x80072EE4: The Visual Elements extension failed while processing the Notification element.   
12/18/2012 3:03:57 PM   10002   Information Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\4850558d-7f7f-4109-9376-3b78bf5acc86_S-1-5-21-1715567821-179605362-839522115-27106_1.rslc for Register Operation on Package cc8bb3bb-d444-4dbe-ae12-64684b12b727_1.0.0.0_neutral__2awvr17ztw74c.    
12/18/2012 3:03:57 PM   603 Information Started deployment Register operation on a package with main parameter: file:///C:/Users/myself/documents/visual%20studio%202012/Projects/TestDeploy/TestDeploy/bin/Debug/AppX/AppxManifest.xml. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.   
12/18/2012 3:03:57 PM   301 Information The calling process is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Any ideas?  I've given full control to everyone on the project, have restarted multiple times, tried reinstalling visual studio, and am running Visual Studio as an administrator.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you got the latest SDK and installed any pending Windows Updates?

Comment: How is deploying to a local machine, so not the simulator. I've seen strange errors occure due to the simulator when making my own project

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything is fully up to date.  Same error happens when I deploy to my local machine :(

Comment: The answer is in the message `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160`  Which tells you to look in the event log.  Which you didn't do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this to "work" by killing and restarting explorer.exe based on suggestions from a different google search I found.  Doesn't really make sense to me, or seem to work reliably, but it does work sometimes at least... o.O

*edit*

A more permanent solution that worked was some combination of reinstalling Visual Studio 2012 and installing Visual Studio Update 1.

Comment: my VS 2013 Preview face this problem also, do I need reinstall vs2012 or vs2013? I have try reinstall vs2013, but not work!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error  and in my case neither cycling explorer.exe nor uninstalling/reinstalling Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 3 worked.

What did work was starting up Visual Studio 2012 with "run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

Seems, the issue has to do something to installing app both to local machine and to simulator

Answer (score 0):

My case is i duplicate a WP 8.1 project and add merge some code to the duplicated project.
After i done the merge, I got "Package can't be registered" message when i deploy it to emulator.

But my original WP 8.1 project is successfully running on the emulator.

The root cause is i delete some app logo png image.
The VS2013 wont tell u that image is missing but display "Package can't be registered".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me after uninstalling a custom app that was installed using VS and trying to re-install a new version through either VS or directly using the `Add-AppDevPackage.ps1` script

While it is not what you want to hear, a reboot fixed this for me.  I tried killing the explorer process and restarting it as mentioned above, but this did not work for me.